# how to match list of dictionaries to another list of dictionaries value where key is different?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an issue where matching two list of dictionaries. Below the code i tried to match.

```
listDict1= [
    '{"weightMax":150, "weightMin":100, "date":"2017-07-05 12:16:06"}',
    '{"weightMax":150, "weightMin":100, "date":"2017-07-05 12:17:06"}',
    '{"weightMax":0, "weightMin":0, "date":"0"}']

listDict2= [
    '{"Weight":"138.0","unit":"Kg",
      "measurementTime":"2017-07-05 12:15:06",
      "receiptTime":"2017-06-30T15:16:09.009-07:00",
      "date":1498860969000,"model":"2011",
      "manufacturer":"CONTINUA","serialnumber":"SN_WEIGHT082"}',
    '{"Weight":"138.0","unit":"Kg",
      "measurementTime":"2017-07-05 12:16:06",
      "receiptTime":"2017-06-30T15:16:09.009-07:00",
      "date":1498860969000,"model":"2011",
      "manufacturer":"CONTINUA","serialnumber":"SN_WEIGHT082"}',
    '{"Weight":"188.0","unit":"Kg",
      "measurementTime":"2017-07-05 12:17:06",
      "receiptTime":"2017-06-30T15:16:09.009-07:00",
      "date":1498860969000,"model":"2011",
      "manufacturer":"CONTINUA","serialnumber":"SN_WEIGHT082"}']
```

I need to match listDict1['date'] value with listDict2['measurementTime']

I tried the code below, but it matches as per the list index

```
def matchValValues(listDict1, listDict2):
    val1 = []
    rpm = []


    for i in range(len(listDict1)):
        j = dict((k, v) for k, v in ast.literal_eval(listDict1[i]).iteritems())
        k = dict((k, v) for k, v in ast.literal_eval(listDict2[i]).iteritems())
        #for i in j.keys():
        val = j['date']
        we = k['measurementTime']
        if val in we :
            val2 = float(k['Weight'])
            max=  float(j['weightMax'])
            min = float(j['weightMin'])
            print "True"
            if val2 <= max and val2 >= min:
                print "pass"
                val1.append(str(j['weightMax'])+'|'+str(j['weightMin']))
                rpm.append(k['Weight'])
            else:
                val1.append(j.copy())
                rpm.append(k.copy())
        else:
            val1.append(j.copy())
            rpm.append(k.copy())
    print val1  
    print rpm
```

expected output:
if there is a match append only weight and measurementTime value in rpm
if there is a match append only weightmax, weightmin and date value in val1
else append whole unmatched dict in rpm and val1 corresponding.

current output:

```
[{'date': '2017-07-05 12:16:06', 'weightMax': 150, 'weightMin': 100},
 {'date': '2017-07-05 12:17:06', 'weightMax': 150, 'weightMin': 100},
 {'date': '0', 'weightMax': 0, 'weightMin': 0}]

[{'Weight': '138.0', 'measurementTime': '2017-07-05 12:15:06',
  'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'date': 1498860969000L,
  'model': '2011', 'receiptTime': '2017-06-30T15:16:09.009-07:00',
  'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'},
 {'Weight': '138.0', 'measurementTime': '2017-07-05 12:15:06',
  'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'date': 1498860969000L,
  'model': '2011', 'receiptTime': '2017-06-30T15:16:09.009-07:00',
  'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'},
 {'Weight': '188.0', 'measurementTime': '2017-07-05 12:16:06',
  'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'date': 1498860969000L,
  'model': '2011', 'receiptTime': '2017-06-30T15:16:09.009-07:00',
  'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It matches per the list index, because that's exactly what you told it to do.  Computers are annoying in this respect.

Don't use the index for choosing the needed `listDict2` entry.  Instead, fetch the date from `listIndex1[i]` and search `listDict2[<all>]['measurementTime']` for that value.  If the lists are large, you might want to build a reverse dictionary of `<time stamp> : index` to make your work easier.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do that? I am trying to figure out.

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?  There are several steps to this, and SO is not a code-writing or tutorial service.  Your code shows that you know how to extract a value from a dictionary entry.  Searching a list for a value is the `index` method.  `Reverse dictionary` is a simple browser search.